# Powershell - Couldn't add 2nd and 3rd date modify parameter

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting

I could manage to retrieve user accounts from DC with their time related parameters like lastlogon, whencreated etc and I could manage to change lastLogon parameter to my prefer (dd.MM.yyyy). But I couldn't make the same conversion to "whenCreated" and "PasswordLastSet" dates.

```
Get-Aduser  -Filter * -Properties *|Select name,SamAccountName,PasswordExpired,description,whenCreated,PasswordLastSet,Enabled,DistinguishedName,DisplayName,GivenName,SurName, @{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')}} |export-csv C:\result.csv
```

I need your help on this issue. How can I modify the 3 dates format into my preferrings at the same time.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{N='whenCreated'; E={$_.whenCreated.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')}}, @{N='PasswordLastSet'; E={$_.PasswordLastSet.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')}}
```

Without 'FromFileTime'.